# Modify .tt File c# for generate inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity, t4

Is there a way to modify `.tt` (t4 template) files so when it generated the classes, they would have inheritance?

I've tried the snippet below but no luck.

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#> : EntityBase
```

Comment: Can you also clarify a bit better? Are you looking to inherit from EntityBase?

Comment: Yes, from EntityBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, i must to add the inheritance in EntityClassOpening

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
     return string.Fromat(
      ...
      "{0} {1} partial class {2}{3} : EntityBase"
      ...
      )
}
```